# Favicon ico doesn't work

Tags: html, favicon

```
<link rel='shortcut icon' href='img/favicon.ico'>
```

The above line is inside `head` part of page.
`favicon.ico` is inside `img` folder.
Doesn't work in Firefox and Chrome.

I restarted browsers, cleared the cache many times...

Any suggestion.

I also tried:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You forgot to self-close the link tag.

I think it is recommended to use double quotes as well:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico"/>
```

If this doesn't work, have you tried to actually access the favicon image by typing the url like: `http://example.org/img/favicon.ico` to make sure it is reachable ?

Comment: In general, looks like favicon can't work because of invalid html. So make sure your html is valid. I had a mistake in my html - left a quote symbol after a canonical tag and that caused faviocon disappear. `<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com" /> "` - it was something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon"
   href="image/favicon.ico"/>
```

without the "shortcut"

if that doesn't help, you might find something in this 
[Wikipedia article on favicon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon)

Answer (score -2):

If any of the other answers don't work, just put `!` in front of the tag.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: two of the answers did not work on firefox, I put ! and it worked out. shortest answer is better.